# Sharepoint Calendar view use wrong URLs for items from overlayed calendars

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have Main calendar, and calendars A and B. A and B are overlaid over Main calendar. I also have filtering on Main calendar to hide some items.

Problem is that in main calendar ALL items from calendar B have URL from calendar A.

I have checked that in overlay settings B have proper URL and list chosen.

Comment: I have simulated your requirements with OOB calenders but not able to reproduce the issue. Can you please give more details and confirm that you are not using any scripts on  that page?

Comment: I only changed content type to one derived from event. (Few extra columns)

Comment: Also when first creating overlay for B, I sticked to auto resolve, which picked A list name. But I have fixed that now, and B overlay use B list.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the same thing happen when we migrated site to different farm, so you may need to create new main overly Calendar view again.

Answer (score 1):

ListFormUrl needs to be updated in your calendar.aspx file via SharePoint Designer.  There should be one for each of your overlays.

Answer (score 1):

Each calendar has its own columns / views. Adding an overlay will copy the calendar data will depend on what calendar you pulling from.

If you create filters on your Main calendar it will only affect the calendar data created in that calendar and not overlay data that is stored in Calendar B. Remember overlays point to calendar views that can be in the same calendar or in a different calendar. Either way the overlay is subject to the columns and view filters of that calendar view wherever it resides. (also consider the location / permissions)